# Node Addons and v8 GlobalTemplate

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8, node.js-addon

I am building node addon with node `0.10.17` and in one of my class i am making a context of v8. I have this code :

```
v8::Locker locker;
v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> globalTemplate;

// vvv--------------- Exception here at ->Set()
globalTemplate->Set(v8::String::New("version"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(NodeVersion));
context = v8::Context::New(NULL, globalTemplate);
if (context.IsEmpty()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error creating context\n");
}
```

This is giving me exception in `->Set()` function call. 
The application is just breaking.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `globalTemplate` pointer is null, since you only created a null v8::Handle.

You should do something like this:

```
v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate> globalTemplate = v8::ObjectTemplate::New();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake. Now it is giving exception on line `context = v8::Context::New(NULL, globalTemplate);`